# Keyboard not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, mouse

I am new to Linux. On my laptop the keyboard was working just fine until I chose to install Ubuntu.

The mouse works well, but I have to use the on screen keyboard to type anything, which is actually very uncomfortable.

Now, how can I make this keyboard work again by only using the mouse. I tried to reinstall the OS but the issue remains the same.

What are some other options I can try?

Comment: Please provide more information. What laptop model do you have? What OS were you using where the keyboard worked? Does plugging in an external keyboard work?

Comment: i am using LG laptop RD 400 Xnote, I was using windows Vista and was working fine. I havent tried the external keyboard yet.